# cakephp create simple buttons that redirects to views

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

i'm starting working with cakephp and i'm having some problems in building the following:
i want the main page of my application have 4 simple buttons, that redirects to different created views. How can i do that?

I tried this:

```
   <?php
echo $this->Form->create('Post');
echo $this->Form->button('Redirect1', array('type'=>'button'));
echo $this->Form->button('Redirect1', array('type'=>'button'));
echo $this->Form->button('Redirect1', array('type'=>'button'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

but i guess is no need for a submit form right? However i didn't found other way in my searches. Is not possible just to change page on button click?

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

Form buttons should not be used as simple links, anyway, you create the button and then adding some javascript or jQuery to make it work as you want as Justin said. (although i usually prefer to use an external .js file with the code)

Another option, would be adding an style for the link which could give it the appearance of a button, for example:

```
echo $this->Html->link("Demo", array('controller' => 'yourcontroller','action'=> 'youraction', $possibleParameter), array( 'class' => 'button'))
```

Where button could be defined as:

```
a.button {
    color: #6e6e6e;
    font: bold 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -webkit-transition: border-color .218s;
    -moz-transition: border .218s;
    -o-transition: border-color .218s;
    transition: border-color .218s;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 40%,0% 70%,from(#F5F5F5),to(#F1F1F1));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(linear,0% 40%,0% 70%,from(#F5F5F5),to(#F1F1F1));
    border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
a.button:hover{
    color: #333;
    border-color: #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
a.button:active {
    color: #000;
    border-color: #444;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, just two more questions please since i'm still having problems concerning this new framework i'm using.
The CSS code, where should i put it? In a .css file inside the views folder?
And about that "$possibleParameter" you used as example, i still could not understand how can i define this parameters outside the link/url code.
There is some example in bookcakephp or can you give one?
Thanks!

Comment: CSS files are located inside `app\webroot\css` as detailed in here:http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html#the-app-folder

And you can include them in your views using the Html helper as its said here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#using-helpers

Anyway, you can always add them directly on the header of your `default.ctp` layout using the `<style> </style>` tags.

Answer (score 5):

I found that question while searching for similar problem. In my opinion easiest way to do that would be that:

```
$this->Html->link($this->Form->button('Button'), array('action' => 'viewSomethin',$id), array('escape'=>false,'title' => "Click to view somethin"));
```

Maybe that will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need links which you would later style with css(assuming you're using the Html helper):

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->link('Click Here', '/redirect/url', array('class' => 'button')); 
?>
```

Read more here: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1442/link

Comment: That's it Nebojsac, but is not possible to surrond a button with this? In this format with will be a text with an href.

Comment: Steve answered that for you I see

Answer (score 2):

You can add a Html rule attribute to your link. This rule will set the link as a button.

```
echo $this->Html->link('Blogs', 
    array('action' => 'add'), 
    array(
        'bootstrap-type' => 'primary',
        'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block',
        // transform link to a button
        'rule' => 'button'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('ADD New One', '/controllername/functionname')?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below will work for you

```
$this->Form->button('Home', 
      array('onclick' => "location.href='".$this->Html->url($url)."'"));
```

Comment: Justin, but now i have to define $url parameters below right?

Comment: Yes, you need to define url.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is using postButton such as:

```
echo $this->Form->postButton('Text Button', array('controller'=>'controllername','action'=>'action_to_do'));
```

You have to change 'controllername' and 'action_to_do' with what you need

Answer (score 0):

I also was just looking about this "problem". But I wasn't happy with the buttons of the form and I just want to get buttons like in the action class: [image]

So I found 2 solutions for me:

**Solution 1: Wrap the button in a span with the css class "action"**

```
<span class="action">
    <?php
    echo $this->Html->link("Send Again", "url");
    ?>
</span>
```

The css class `action` is already meant in the cake.generic stylesheet. So it will be directly a nice button.

**Solution 2: Copy the css styles for `.actions a`**

This solution is more an addition to [Alvaro's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13492220/2625488). I can't comment yet, so I have to do an extra answer for that.

So, I didn't use Alvaro's css as they are for the form buttons and slightly different to the original ones. So I just searched for the styles for `.action a` in the original `cake.generic.css` and copied them in my own css file and changed the selector to `a.button`.

Then now you can use this to generate the button without any wrapper:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link("Send Again, "url", ["class" => "button"]) ?>
```

The css for **CakePHP** version **2.6.2**:

```
a.button {
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background: #dcdcdc;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fefefe), to(#dcdcdc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dcdcdc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dcdcdc);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dcdcdc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dcdcdc);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dcdcdc);
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: #fff 0px 1px 0px;
  min-width: 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

a.button:hover {
  background: #ededed;
  border-color: #acacac;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.button:active {
  background: #eee;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#dfdfdf), to(#eee));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dfdfdf, #eee);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dfdfdf, #eee);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #dfdfdf, #eee);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #dfdfdf, #eee);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #dfdfdf, #eee);
  text-shadow: #eee 0px 1px 0px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-color: #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Hope it will help guys three years after the question was asked. :D

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 2.X

```
 <button id="create_task_groups" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $this->Html>url(array('plugin'=>'task_calendar', 'controller'=>'task_groups', 'action'=>'add'))?>'"> Create Task Group</button>
```